# Restrict admin Hyperv rights

Tags: hyper-v, cluster

I use a Hyper-V 2008 R2 cluster, and I've two types of admin (full admin and management server admin).

I would like to give to the management server admin only the right to start/shutdown the virtual machine but I don't want that they could create, delete or modify the existing virtual machine.

Is it possible to do that and how?

Answer (score 2):

The authorization model does allow these things, but it's far from simple to explain.  Start reading John Howard's blog on the topic:

http://blogs.technet.com/jhoward/archive/2009/08/31/explaining-the-hyper-v-authorization-model-part-one.aspx